# My implementation of FixedSizedPriorityQueue

Tags: java, priority-queue

I implemented a fixed sized priority queue.
How can I improve my code?

```
public class FixedSizedPriorityQueue {
    private final int capacity;
    private boolean sorted = false;
    private double smallest = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
    private ArrayList<Double> list;

    protected static final Comparator<Double> comparator = new Comparator<Double>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Double o1, Double o2) {
            return o2.compareTo(o1);
        }
    };

    public FixedSizedPriorityQueue(int capacity) {
        this.capacity = capacity;
        list = new ArrayList<Double>(capacity);
    }

    public void add(double value) {
        if (list.size() < capacity) {
            list.add(value);
            sorted = false;
            if (value < smallest) {
                smallest = value;
            }
        } else {
            if (value > smallest) {
                if (!sorted) {
                    Collections.sort(list, comparator);
                    sorted = true;
                }
                list.set(capacity - 1, value);
                if (list.get(capacity - 2) > value) {
                    smallest = value;
                } else {
                    smallest = list.get(capacity - 2);
                    sorted = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public int getSize() {
        return list.size();
    }

    public Double poll() {
        if (list.size() == 0) return null;
        if (!sorted) {
            Collections.sort(list, comparator);
            sorted = true;
        }
        Double value = list.get(0);
        list.remove(0);
        if (list.size() == 0) smallest = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
        return value;
    }

    public void print() {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(i + ": " + list.get(i));
        }
        System.out.println("Smallest: " + smallest);
    }
}
```

Comment: You may want to implement the [Queue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) interface as well

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. The following is used multiple times and it could be extracted out:

   ```
   if (!sorted) {
       Collections.sort(list, comparator);
       sorted = true;
   }
   ```

   to a helper method:

   ```
   private void sortIfNeccessary() {
       if (sorted) {
           return;
       }
       Collections.sort(list, comparator);
       sorted = true;
   }
   ```

   Note the [guard clause](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/01/flattening-arrow-code.html).
2. `List.remove` returns the removed elements.

   ```
   Double value = list.get(0);
   list.remove(0);
   ```

   The code above could be simplified to this:

   ```
   final Double value = list.remove(0);
   ```
3. The comparator could be substituted with the `reverseOrder` method/comparator:

   ```
   Collections.sort(list, Collections.reverseOrder());
   ```
4. The `list` could be `final`. `final` helps readers, because they know that the reference always points to the same instance and it doesn't change later. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/115690/why-declare-final-variables-inside-methods but you can find other questions on Programmers.SE in the topic.
5. Furthermore, its type could be only `List<Double>` instead of `ArrayList<Double>`. See: *Effective Java, 2nd edition*, *Item 52: Refer to objects by their interfaces*
6. The `print` method violates the [single responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). Other clients may want to write the elements to a log file or a network socket so you shouldn't mix the queue logic with the printing. I'd consider creating a `List<Double> getElements` method (which would return a copy or unmodifiable version of `list` to make sure that malicious clients does not modify the inner state of the queue) or providing an iterator to clients and move the `print` method to another class.
7. Does it make sense to create a queue with negative capacity? If not, check it and throw an `IllegalArgumentException`. 
   Actually, it does not work with capacities less than 2. It throws a `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1` when the capacity is 1 because of the `list.get(capacity - 2)` call. (*Effective Java, Second Edition*, *Item 38: Check parameters for validity*)

   ```
   public FixedSizedPriorityQueue(final int capacity) {
       if (capacity < 2) {
           throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal capacity: " + capacity);
       }
       ...
   }
   ```
8. Instead of

   ```
   if (list.size() == 0) ...
   ```

   you could use

   ```
   if (list.isEmpty()) ...
   ```

   It's the same but easier to read.

Answer (score 3):

I think your code would be a lot simpler if you kept your list sorted at all times. It would also probably be faster. Constantly resorting the list is going to more expensive then inserting new items in the proper location. You might be saving a little by not sorting in certain cases, but probably less then you lose by having to resort the list rather then just insert in the correct location.

You could also consider using a data structure such as a heap. Heaps are often used for priority queues. It lets you fetch the smallest element, but is cheaper then the expense of maintaing a sorted list.

Comment: I think you didn't look at my code very carefully. I DON'T insert a new element in a correct location. I rather use a lazy ordered list, so sorting only occurs when it is really needed. As I understand, to implement such a lazy style priority queue, heaps cannot be used.

Comment: @heejin there seems to be a misunderstanding here. Winston was suggesting that you **don't** lazy-sort. He *does* recommend that you insert items in the correct location instead.

Comment: Arghhhh sorry for my poor English. I was confused. Sorry, Winston!